# What's the use of asio::placeholder::error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

The asio library passes an error parameter in a lot of its examples, ie;
http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.5.3/src/examples/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp

What's the point of this parameter? Does asio actually populate this parameter with errors?

If I remove it from my handler function it compiles fine.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, `asio::placeholders::error` is equivalent to `_1` Boost.Bind placeholder, so `bind(&my_class::handler, this, asio::placeholders::error)` is just like `bind(&my_class::handler, this, _1)`.

When this handler is being called by Boost.Asio completion-handler dispatcher, `error_code` is passed as the 1st argument to this function.

However, you can always `bind` a function that expects less arguments (in this case - zero) - when the binder gets invoked, [any extra arguments are silently ignored](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/bind/bind.html#with_functions).